# Union and difference between two sets using only Symmetric Difference and Intersection operation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Write the union and difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ using only the symmetric difference $\bigtriangleup$ and intersection $\cap$ operations.

NOTE: For $A$ and $B$ subsets of $\Omega$, we define
$$
A - B = A \cap \neg B
$$
($\neg B$ is the complement set of $B$)

I can't actually think of a solution to this problem that use only those two operations.

My answer to the union was
$$
(A \bigtriangleup B) \cup (A \cap B), 
$$
but the question states that we are supposed to use only two operations defined.

For the difference I been thinking about a way to solve the problem but it's not clear to me.

Comment: Can you also refer to the complement of a set?

Comment: If we aren't allowed to use complementation, I don't think union is possible. But if we are allowed to use complementation, then $A^c \Delta B^c$ is basically $A \cup B$ minus $A \cap B$. That is, this operation has taken too out of what we want. So we might want to shrink the arguments in $A^c \Delta B^c$. Any idea how we would do that?

Comment: Hint: if two sets $C$ and $D$ are disjoint (i.e. $C \cap D = \varnothing$), what is a simpler way to write $C \bigtriangleup D$?

Comment: Your answer to the union uses the union operation.

Answer (score 2):

$$A \cup B = (A \triangle B) \triangle (A \cap B)$$

$$A - B = (A\triangle B) \cap A$$

It helps to draw some Venn diagrams.

Also, note that if, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then the symmetric difference is the same as a union. That's leveraged in the first equation.